# angular rendering of css moves z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following css:

```
# this is the grey line
ul.timeline-list > li.media:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 58px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.timeline-list > li.media:before {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}

#this is the image icon
ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Html looks like:

```
<ul ng-app="edgeFeed" class="timeline-list ng-scope">
<li class="media media-clearfix-xs">
<div class="media-left">
                      <div class="user-wrapper">
                        <img ng-src="myimage.jpg"  class="img-circle" width="80" src="myimage.jpg">
                        <div><a href="#" class="ng-binding">some entry</a></div>
                        <div class="date"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the image goes behind the grey vertical line but should be behind it like the image above.  Also the image should aligned:

[image]

**How can I get the image to stay above the grey line?**

Comment: What is the z-index of the grey line? (use your browser's dev tool to check) And can you increase the z-index of your image? To let say 100 or 1000?

Comment: @OscarSiauw the grey line is the entry with 1 above and the image is 2 above.  I did the increase and no change, angular is suppressing it somehow.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: try to make important like this

ul.timeline-list > li.media > .media-left {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
}